# I want to play one podcast only on iPod Touch, but they play in series one after the other

Tags: ipod-touch, podcasts

I download multiple podcasts from one source, eg, five episodes of Naked Scientists.  I want to listen to one only, but when the first finishes it automatically goes to the second, and third etc.

I want to listen to just one episode at a time and have the iPod Touch turn off when it is finished (this is a sleep-aid for my insomnia...I don't want it playing all night !)

A "Genius" suggested making playlists, but although you can make a podcast playlist, it does NOT sync.

Comment: thanks all - I'll try the next couple nights and report back to this page.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 4, you can make a playlist directly on your device. Go to the Music app, then Playlists, then "Add Playlist...". Type in the name for the playlist, hit Save, and you're presented with a screen to add items to the playlist. Select "Podcasts" (by default, it's found under "More") and select the item you want to play. Tap "Done".

You're all set - just select the item from the playlist and only that item will play.

Comment: Kyle - thank you, thank you, thank you.
Tried it and it works.  Seems there is "always" a way to outsmart the machine.
Go it to work for one, now I will make a little library and I see no reason why it won't work.
Greatly appreciated.
Ed

Answer (score 2):

Use the On-The-Go playlist and add the one podcast episode to it. Works from at least iOS 3 or possibly before.

You don't event need to clear the existing playlist, because adding a track will add to the end, so just start from that track and it will stop at the end (unless you have repeat on).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a smart playlist. Set it up with the following rule:
- Name is {the podcast's name}
- Plays is 0

Limit it to 1 item, selected by least recently added.

Check the "live updating" box.

This should give you a playlist with one track - the oldest unheard episode of the podcast.

I've used a variation on this and it is able to sync to my iPhone (once I selected it to be included in the sync).